# Rails gem : javan whenever failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, whenever

Trying to set up javan Whenever gem.

Have the 0.8.4 version installed.

schedule.rb looks like this :

```
if Rails.env == 'production'
  set :output, "#{::Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/cron.log"

  every '*/1 * * * *' do
    command "bundle exec rake ts:reindex RAILS_ENV=production"
  end
end
```

When I do a 'whenever' I get :

```
/home/slagrz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/whenever-0.6.8/lib/whenever/job_list.rb:21:in `eval': uninitialized constant Whenever::JobList::Rails (NameError)
    from /home/slagrz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/whenever-0.6.8/lib/whenever/job_list.rb:21:in `eval'
    from /home/slagrz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/whenever-0.6.8/lib/whenever/job_list.rb:21:in `initialize'
    from /home/slagrz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/whenever-0.6.8/lib/whenever.rb:15:in `new'
    from /home/slagrz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/whenever-0.6.8/lib/whenever.rb:15:in `cron'
    from /home/slagrz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/whenever-0.6.8/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:41:in `run'
    from /home/slagrz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/whenever-0.6.8/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:8:in `execute'
    from /home/slagrz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/whenever-0.6.8/bin/whenever:38:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/slagrz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/whenever:23:in `load'
    from /home/slagrz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/whenever:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/slagrz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /home/slagrz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

So, just wondering if I have wrong versions installed or if the format of the schedule file is affecting it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On further investigation I commented out lines as follows and its working now from the command line.

```
#if Rails.env == 'production'
#  set :output, "#{::Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/cron.log"

  every '*/1 * * * *' do
    command "bundle exec rake ts:reindex RAILS_ENV=production"
  end
#end
```

I think this was intented for use with capistrano originally.. maybe?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error in my rails 4.1 application for below code:

```
every 1.day, :at => '8:30 am' do
  rake 'update_hotels', environment: Rails.env
end
```

I tried updating crontab with whenever command ( whenever --update-crontab ) and got the error.

I managed to get it working by removing environment part ( environment: Rails.env ).

However I had to manually update crontab as it generated entries for production environment but I was trying this in staging.